# React paypal button v2 sandbox to live

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal-buttons

I have made it with sandbox account.

I followed steps to get client id from "LIVE" rest API, after doing that, swapped it with the test one ClientId, how ever its still showing the sandbox one.

Is there a time gap where it needs to refresh? Or am I doing something wrong.

my paypal button is:

```
<PayPalButton
    amount={this.state.price}
    onSuccess={this.completeElementFunction}
    shippingPreference="NO_SHIPPING"
    options={{
        clientId: "someClientId123",
        currency: "USD"
    }}
/>
```

Maybe there is some kind of option to set it by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm, sorry, seems like I forgot to build and the old API key was integrated.

**Explanation:**
Paypal decides if its sandbox or production by the key, so you have to create a key that is meant for live, update it and it will work fine.

*This is for who ever will run into similar problem and maybe find it.*

Comment: I used the live client Id, but still PayPal button is opening in sandbox, while the payment with credit card is working fine though

Comment: @RaghuVallikkat If I recall there is ID and Key, so make sure that both are productions